# Background image overriding background color

Tags: jquery, html, css, google-analytics

In order to do some email tracking with google I need to set a background 'image' containing the event data on the elements I want to track.

Doing this applies a white background to any text that is within that element.

I've tried

`.css('background','inherit url(...)');`

`.css({'background-image':'url(...)','background-color': inherit);`

`.style.backgroundImage="url(...)"; & .style.backgroundColor="inherit";`

- If i set a different image it all works but it doens't make sense the issue is the image because before the JS I did everything manually and it worked fine
- After running the script to set the images and trying to set the color manually either nothing happens or if done from the inspection panel, the property immediately disappears after being set

Running my full JS code you see the color get set, then be overriden by the images.

```
      function autoTag(element, category, action, campaign, medium, source) {
        var elem = $(element);

        var clientId = Math.round(2147483647 * Math.random()); //replace with LM UUID
        var UAcode = 'tid=UA-XXXXXXXX-X';

        for (i = 0; i < elem.length; i++) {
          var label = elem[i].getAttribute("href");
          $(elem[i]).css('background','inherit url(http://www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&tid='+UAcode+'&cid='+clientId+'&t=event&ea='+action+'&ec='+category+'&el='+label+'&cs='+source+'&cm='+medium+'&cn='+campaign+')');
        }

      }

      //Call function
      autoTag('a', 'testCat', 'testLink', 'testCamp', 'testMed', 'testSRC');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a pseudo element to color the background:

https://css-tricks.com/tinted-images-multiple-backgrounds/